# How resolve the error: Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError? React

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, codesandbox

I'm trying to write a code in the codesandbox, but it's with an error. I have to do a check through the ternary.

```
TypeError
Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: /src/components/SearchResults.js: Unexpected token (8:10)

   6 |       {filteredProducts().map((product) => {
   7 |         filteredProducts().length > 0 (
>  8 |           return (
     |           ^
   9 |             <div key={product.id}>
  10 |               <li>{product.title}</li>
  11 |             </div>'
```

To solve the problem I used the ternary with the ? and :
Am I doing something wrong what could it be? Someone can help me?

**Component with error**

```
import React from "react";
const SearchResults = ({ filteredProducts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {filteredProducts().map((product) => {
        filteredProducts().length > 0 (
          return (
            <div key={product.id}>
              <li>{product.title}</li>
            </div>
          )
        ) : (
          return(
            <p>Item not found</p>
          )
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResults;
```

[Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-product-redux-c1dqys?file=/src/components/SearchResults.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should check the length before the map statement like this:

```
import React from "react"

const SearchResults = ({ filteredProducts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {filteredProducts.length > 0 ? (
        filteredProducts().map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id}>
            <li>{product.title}</li>
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>Item not found</p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchResults
```

Answer (score 4):

you cannot have `return` inside (expression) becuase it is not a function

Also, the ternary syntax has "?" like this

```
 expressionIfTrue ? (take this) : (If exp not true take this)

import React from "react";
const SearchResults = ({ filteredProducts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {filteredProducts().map((product) => {
        filteredProducts().length > 0 ? (
          <div key={product.id}>
            <li>{product.title}</li>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <p>Item not found</p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResults;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue because of implicitly return was not declared inside map.

```
type numberArray = number[];

interface listType {
  name: string;
  color: string;
  data: numberArray[];
}
```

where plots as listType, and writing the map like:

```
yAxis: plots.map(p => {
  labels: {...}, 
  title: {text: p.name}
})
```

which I replaced as below said, and my issue got resolved by wrapping the inner curly braces using parenthesis or either create another object and return that object explicitly inside the inner curly brace.

```
yAxis: plots.map(p => ({
  labels: {...}, 
  title: {text: p.name}
}))
```

Hope this would help many one.

Answer (score 0):

If still anybody facing the issue, please cross check if the file extension is  `.tsx` instead of `.ts`. In my case I was writing a component inside a `.ts` file which is not allowed by code-sandbox.